# $L/k$ forms for affine schemes of finite type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, galois-cohomology

***Notations and terminology***:  Let $k$ be a field and $X$ be a $k$-scheme. Denote by $X_L$ the scheme $X\times_k\rm Spec(L)$. For a field extension $L/k$, *a $L/k$ form* is a $k$-scheme $Y$ such that there is a $L$ isomorphism $X_L\cong Y_L$. For a galois extension $L/k$ with the galois group $\rm Gal(L/k)$, we denote isomorphism classes of $L/k$ forms by  $A(L/k)$. For $\sigma\in\rm Gal(L/k)$ we obtain an automorphism $\sigma f$ of $X_L$ which is given by $\sigma f=(1\otimes\sigma)f(1\otimes\sigma)^{-1}$

Now there is injection $\phi: A(L/k)\to H^1(L/k,\rm Aut_L(X))$; here $\phi$ is given as follows: Let $Y\in A(L/k)$ and fix $f:X_L\to Y_L$. For every $\sigma\in G$ we define 1-cocycle $a_\sigma=f^{-1}(\sigma f)$. Here $H^1(L/k, \rm Aut_L(X))$ is first non-abelian cohomology group.

It is easy to see that the map $\phi$ injective.

**Question:** 1. If we assume our $k$-scheme is affine of finite type then how  does one show that the map $\phi$ is surjective? 2. What other schemes there are  for which the map $\phi$ is surjective?

Note that for an affine $k$ scheme $X$, any $L/k$ form $Y$ must be affine $k$ scheme. So for Question 1 we require to find affine $k$ schems.  I am not able to think a way to construct an affine $k$ scheme $Y\in A(L/k)$ which will be corresponds to given $a_\sigma\in H^1(L/k, \rm Aut_L(X))$.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you look up the keywords "Galois descent" or "etale descent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Serre, Galois cohomology], Chapter III, §1 Forms, and the references there ([Serre, Local Fields], X.§2, and [Giraud, Cohomologie Non Abélienne]).

Comment: Thank you! I have little doubt though. As given by Serre, we have representation of $\rm Gal(L/k)$ in $\rm Aut_k(X_L)$ $h(\sigma)=a_\sigma.(1\otimes \sigma)$. Then for $Y$ we can consider $X_L/h(\rm h(Gal(L/k)))$. Why this $Y$ will be of finite type?